# Grab jQuery set CSS class

Tags: jquery, css

My scenario is this:

I'm runing Contact Form 7 (contactform7.com). When a user have'nt set the required fields and pressed send (the form is sent with jQuery, so a page reload is'nt initiated) the Contact Form 7 script outputs a "error class" to the input field where the user have missed to fill out.

This class - which the Contact Form 7 have set - I want to grab. But it seems that hasClass() does'nt work on this. It just works on predefined classes.

My conclusion is that the class which hasClass() tries to grab is'nt available at some how when the whole page is'nt reloaded.

How do I solve this and can be able to grab the class?

Edit: I have this code

```
$('input:text, textarea').click(function() {
        $(this).css({'background' : '#fff'});
    });
```

If you have missed to fill out a required input/textarea and pressed "Send", the field comes up with a red background (this is right). The above code makes them white on click (this is right). But if you forget to fill a required input/textarea the second time and pressed "Send", the field you have forgot to write something in comes up as white (background) and not red (this is wrong).

My thoughts is that the above code overrides the other CSS classes. How do I avoid this?

Comment: How you are achieving the red background on the first time when submitted with an error? Please paste the code with the html..

Comment: The Contact Form 7 adds a class - on submit - to the input/textarea - if the required field is not set - which I have then set a "background: red" to in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are using contact form 7( i hope in wordpress) you can directly edit the javascript of the contactform7. so to make hasClass() working you should write it in that file by binding it with some event like for example on Click of submit button.

and for the error styling you should not add new inline styles because when the form is validated next time it will remove the applied error class(if no validation error are not there) and add error class (if validation error was there) but your style will retain there and override the applied class. So instead of adding new styles onclick of textarea or text box remove the applied error class for it

for example:-

```
$('input:text, textarea').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('your error class');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment you said it will add a class for the input field if it got error. So write another class for normal.

```
$('input:text, textarea').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('yourErrorClass').addClass('yourNormalClass');
});

.yourNormalClass{
    background : #fff
}
```

Edit : When giving error you are changing the class and to make it normal(background:#fff) you are changing the style of the element. The inline style for the element will be preferred always than class. Thats why second time it will be white as (background:#fff) will be preferred as its the style for the element.